# RxSwift - Arrays merge, sort, remove duplicates

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Consider the following arrays

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let b = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

How to get c, where `c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`? 
In RxSwift, how to do merge, sort, and removing duplicate for the input arrays?

Answer (score 5):

Everything you need is provided by the Core Library:

```
let c = Set(a + b).sorted()
```

Comment: Vote up for the good answer, I tried it and it is working. But I am more interested in RxSwift answer.